# "Cannot find name Map" error in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I have a project which I am handling the front-end with Angular and back-end with ASP.NET. While the back-end server was already working, I was making changes on Angular project and when I wanted to re-run the ASP.NET code, I got an unexpected error at the ASP.NET side even though I did not change anything on the server side. Here is the error;

```
Severity: Error 
Code: Build 
Description: Cannot find name: 'Map'    
Project: WebExperience.Test 
File: D:\Desktop\StyleLabs\node_modules\@types\selenium-webdriver\http.d.ts 
        .
```

What can be causing this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could be a missed import or an issue with the Map import in one of your components, this can happen if you used the auto import and accidentally imported Map from selenium-webdriver instead of rxjs or didnt mean to import at all maybe

Comment: I imported selenium-webdriver accidentally at Angular side, but then I corrected it. Do you think it may be the issue?

Comment: yes maybe it still is in there somwhere in your code search from the side bar for selenium

Comment: @PariBaker, when I search for **"selenium"** keyword, instances are all located in `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: hmm what about Map? Probably in a service that points to the wrong module

Comment: @PariBaker, so many instances for the Map. I think you are right. It points to the `selenium` rather than `common/http`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Well you'll have to go through the components and services and find out where it is pointing to that Map, but why are you importing Map from common/http?

Comment: @PariBaker, I never imported the Map, this is the problem. The Error occurred at the ASP.NET side.

Comment: btw if your trying to import it for an http client then its probably somewhere in a service to use the map operator after and http call you need to import map from rxjs/operator and add it inside a .pipe() so this.http.get().pipe(map=>{res=>res})

Comment: ah okay well it seems to be imported somewhere maybe just a mistype

Comment: @PariBaker, I searched for `rxjs` and `{ Map }` but any instance found in the Angular project.

Comment: have you checked this file?  D:\Desktop\StyleLabs\node_modules\@types\selenium-webdriver\http.d.ts

Comment: @PariBaker yes, actually this is a .cs file where error happens.Well, actually I solved the problem. The ASP.NET project and Angular project was standing in same folder. When I moved the ASP.NET project outside of that folder, it started to build succesfully. Anyways, thank you so much for your help and time.